# Ansible: Assign JSON value to a variable

Tags: json, ansible

I am using a custom facts module to get JSON back in Ansible 2.9

```
ok: [Host] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "Successfully completed the view storage volume operation",
        "storage_status": {
            "Message": {
                "Controller": {
                    "AHCI.Embedded.3-1": {},
                    "RAID.Integrated.1-1": {
                        "Enclosure": {
                            "Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1": {
                                "PhysicalDisk": [
                                    "Disk.Bay.0:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1",
                                    "Disk.Bay.1:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "VirtualDisk": {
                            "Disk.Virtual.0:RAID.Integrated.1-1": {
                                "PhysicalDisk": [
                                    "Disk.Bay.0:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1",
                                    "Disk.Bay.1:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "Status": "Success"
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to assign "`Disk.Virtual.0:RAID.Integrated.1-1`" value to a variable using set_fact module. Using the following filter:

```
{{ disks['storage_status']['Message']['Controller']['RAID.Integrated.1-1']['VirtualDisk'] }}
```

I am able to just select the following:

```
ok : [Host] => {
        "msg": {
            "Disk.Virtual.0:RAID.Integrated.1-1": {
                "PhysicalDisk": [
                    "Disk.Bay.0:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1",
                    "Disk.Bay.1:Enclosure.Internal.0-1:RAID.Integrated.1-1"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am unable to work out how to grab `Disk.Virtual.0:RAID.Integrated.1-1` and assign it to the variable.

Any help/guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict` lookup with `.key`:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('dict', disks['storage_status']['Message']['Controller']['RAID.Integrated.1-1']['VirtualDisk']).key }}"
```

Gives:

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Disk.Virtual.0:RAID.Integrated.1-1"
}
```

To assign to a variable (`my_var`), use `set_fact`:

```
  - set_fact:
      my_var: "{{ lookup('dict', disks['storage_status']['Message']['Controller']['RAID.Integrated.1-1']['VirtualDisk']).key }}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Jack. I tried to mark this answer as solution but due to my reputation I was unable to do so. In addition to what you have already answered may I also ask how can I assign RAID.Integrated.1-1 from the original json to a variable? Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask you how to assign the key RAID.Integrated.1-1 to a separate variable. I am aware and familiar with the set_fact module but I wanted to know the query and assignment of RAID.Integrated.1-1. Thank you again

Comment: Just run it through the `regex_replace` filter: `"{{ ... | regex_replace( '^.*:', '') }}"`

Comment: Really sorry to keep clarifying and asking you.. but I would like to grab the dict object ok: [Host] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "Successfully completed the view storage volume operation",
        "storage_status": {
            "Message": {
                "Controller": {
                    "AHCI.Embedded.3-1": {},
 This -->>     "RAID.Integrated.1-1":           Instead of using regex_replace

Comment: Then I really don't understand what part of that JSON object you want to assign to the variable.